# Сохранение переменной при новом запуске скрипта в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть игра в которой каждый уровень сцена.При переходе на новую сцену скрипт запускается снова и переменная обновляется на ноль.
Нужно сделать подсчет очков (При переходе на новый уровень +1 очко)
Также я хотел спросить, нужно ли прикреплять отдельно текст в котором будут очки к каждой сцене вручную или есть способ попроще?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: или статическая переменная

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сохранения есть 3 способа.

---

## PlayerPrefs

Сохранение в [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) - Это самый лёгкий способ сохранения но его очень легко взломать. Функции `PlayerPrefs.SetInt()`, `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat()`, `PlayerPrefs.SetString()` создают ключи в виде int, float и string и там сохраняют переменные․

```cs
PlayerPrefs.SetInt(*название ключа в котором вы хотите сохранить*,*переменная*);
```

Чтобы в следующем сцене "восстановить" переменную нужно использовать функции `PlayerPrefs.GetInt()`, `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat()`, `PlayerPrefs.GetString()`.

```cs
int value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(*название ключа*);
```

---

## Json

Сохранение в файлах [JSON](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) - Этот способ более надёжный и к тому же удобный но немного сложный. Вы можете создать класс чтобы сохранять несколько переменных или сразу тип файла. Создаём класс например под именем Example, даём ему значение и создаём путь для сохранения.

```cs
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(*имя класса*);
```

Потом загрузка.

```cs
Example value = JsonUtility.FromJson<Example>(json);
```

---

## Общий метод

Сохранение JSON в файлах Player.Prefs - Самый быстрый и самый сложный метод. После сохранения вы можете закодировать ключ и сломать его будет почти невозможно (хотя везде есть способ взломать). Сохранение происходит вот так։

```cs
struct Object
{
    public int variable1;
    public int variable2;
    public int variable3;
}

Object Example = new Object();

Example.variable1 = value1;
Example.variable2 = value2;
Example.variable3 = value3;

PlayerPrefs.SetString(*название ключа*,JsonUtility.ToJson(Example));
```

А загрузка вот так:

```cs
Object LoadedExample = JsonUtility.FromJson<Object>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("saveKey"));

int newVariable1 = LoadedExample.variable1;
int newVariable2 = LoadedExample.variable2;
int newVariable3 = LoadedExample.variable3;
```

Comment: Могу ли я сохранить переменную в одном скрипте а вызвать в другом?(PlayerPrefs)

Comment: @Veudd можете, нужно только каким-то образом хранить ключ для загрузки значений из PlayerPrefs