# Не получается передать значение Dropdown при переходе между сценами в Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не принимается значение `Dropdown`. Я создал GameManager для того, чтобы сохранять данные о переменной очков (`score`), когда перехожу между сценами. Но почему-то значение `Dropdown` не воспринимается. У меня создано 3 сцены. На 1 сцене я повесил `GameManager` и создал скрипт, где создал переменную `score`, чтобы при переходе на следующие сцены `score` был в них. Я использую `InputField` и `Dropdown`. На 1 сцене всё читает и заносит в скрипт, где создал переменную `score`. Но на 2 и 3 сценах `score` не пополняется. В чём может быть проблема? Помогите, пожалуйста.

1 скрипт (с `Dropdown`, со 2 сцены):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Excersice12 : MonoBehaviour
{
private GameObject Manager;

public Dropdown dropdown1;

public Dropdown dropdown2;

public Dropdown dropdown3;

public Dropdown dropdown4;

public Dropdown dropdown5;

public Dropdown dropdown6;

public Dropdown dropdown7;

public Dropdown dropdown8;

void Start()
{
    dropdown1.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown2.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown3.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown4.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown5.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown6.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown7.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown8.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    Manager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").gameObject;

    dropdown1.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate
    {
        if (Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score <= 0) {
        Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = 0;
        }

       else if (dropdown1.value == 4)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
        }
        else {
            //Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
        }
    });

    dropdown2.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate
    {
        if (Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score <= 0)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = 0;
        }

       else if (dropdown2.value == 2)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
        }
        else
        {
          //  Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
        }
    });

    dropdown3.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate
    {
        if (Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score <= 0)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = 0;
        }

       else if (dropdown3.value == 4)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
        }
        else
        {
         //   Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
        }
    });

    dropdown4.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate
    {
        if (Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score <= 0)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = 0;
        }

        else if (dropdown4.value == 2)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
        }
        else
        {
          //  Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
        }
    });

    dropdown5.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate
    {
        if (Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score <= 0)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = 0;
        }

        else if (dropdown5.value == 4)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
        }
        else
        {
            //Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
        }
    });

    dropdown6.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate
    {
        if (Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score <= 0)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = 0;
        }

        else if (dropdown6.value == 3)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
        }
        else
        {
          //  Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
        }
    });

    dropdown7.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate
    {
        if (Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score <= 0)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = 0;
        }

        else if (dropdown7.value == 3)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
        }
        else
        {
            //Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
        }
    });

    dropdown8.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate
    {
        if (Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score <= 0)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = 0;
        }

       else if (dropdown8.value == 2)
        {
            Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
        }
        else
        {
         //   Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
        }
    });
}

void Update()
{

}
}
```

2 скрипт (`GameManager`):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static GameManager instance;

public double score = 0;

void Awake()
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Вы знайте что у вас код максимально медленно будет работать. Вы зачем то добавили 8 слушателей  которые делают примерно то же самое

Comment: @Alt_F4 У меня создано 3 сцены. На 1 сцене я повесил GameManager и создал скрипт, где создал переменную score, чтобы при переходе на следующие сцены score был в них. Я использую InputField и Dropdown. На 1 сцене всё читает и заносит в скрипт, где создал переменную score. Но на 2 и 3 сценах score не пополняется. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сохранить и загрузить значение Dropdown. А на вопрос "как сохранять и загрузить" уже ответили и не один раз. Прочитайте например [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977281/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-unity/977330#977330).

Comment: У меня создано 3 сцены. На 1 сцене я повесил GameManager и создал скрипт, где создал переменную score, чтобы при переходе на следующие сцены score был в них. Я использую InputField и Dropdown. На 1 сцене всё читает и заносит в скрипт, где создал переменную score. Но на 2 и 3 сценах score не пополняется. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: То есть вы всю картину собирайте в 3 сценах. Зачем не в одном, что вам мешает?