# Unity рандомное появление картинок

Tags: c#, unity3d, изображения

Добрые день, оооочень нужна помощь)) 
Сейчас пишу проложение в Unity, 
есть 8 картинок со стрелками, хочу что бы они рандомно появлялись, потом можно их свайпануть в какую то из 4 сторон, и за ней появляется новая, 
не знаю как это сделать(( получилось только разобраться с timerbar, 
прошу о помощи,

Огромное спасибо!!

Comment: Со свайпами не обещаю но всё остальное я вам напишу. Чуть чуть подождите :-)

Comment: у меня есть небольшой кусочек кода, и работает замена фото по нажаю клавиши какой либо, но есть пару вопросиков:  1 - как заменить тач на свайпы,  2 - почему то не получается переместить Sprite повверх  Canvas ,    3 - если я начну считать полученные очки, ка я могу передать их значения в другую сцену (или так вообще можно) что бы та подбила результаты игры. Спасибо огромное за ответ))) @Арман

Comment: 1. Со свайпами не дружу)  2. Любой `Sprite` всегда выше `Canvas`-а  3.[Сохраните данные.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977281)

Answer (score 2):

## Работоспособность

[image]

## Описание

В скрипте всё уже написано, вам надо всего лишь добавить объекты в скрипт и всё будет работать:

[image]

Попробуйте понять что в скрипте написано а не просто скопировать его. Вот и собственно скрипт:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Images: MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Variables
    public Image MainImage, SecondImage;
    public Sprite[] ImagesList;
    private int ImageIndex;
    private bool TopLock = true, RightLock = true, BottomLock = true, LeftLock = true;
    private Vector3 StartPosition, ImageSize;
    public float SwipeTime = 1;
    public Button TopButton, RightButton, BottomButton, LeftButton;
    #endregion

    #region Initialize
    private void Start()
    {
        StartPosition = MainImage.transform.localPosition;
        ImageSize = MainImage.rectTransform.rect.size;

        #region Listeners
        TopButton.onClick.AddListener
        (
            delegate
            {
                SecondImage.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, StartPosition.y - ImageSize.y, 0);
                SecondImage.sprite = NewImage();
                TopLock = false;
            }
        );
        RightButton.onClick.AddListener
        (
            delegate
            {
                SecondImage.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(StartPosition.x - ImageSize.x, 0, 0);
                SecondImage.sprite = NewImage();
                RightLock = false;
            }
        );
        BottomButton.onClick.AddListener
        (
            delegate
            {
                SecondImage.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, StartPosition.y + ImageSize.y, 0);
                SecondImage.sprite = NewImage();
                BottomLock = false;
            }
        );
        LeftButton.onClick.AddListener
        (
            delegate
            {
                SecondImage.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(StartPosition.x + ImageSize.x, 0, 0);
                SecondImage.sprite = NewImage();
                LeftLock = false;
            }
        );
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion

    #region Update
    private void Update()
    {
        if (!TopLock)
        {
            if (SecondImage.transform.localPosition.y < StartPosition.y)
            {
                MainImage.transform.Translate(0, ImageSize.y * Time.deltaTime / SwipeTime, 0);
                SecondImage.transform.Translate(0, ImageSize.y * Time.deltaTime / SwipeTime, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                MainImage.transform.localPosition = StartPosition;
                SecondImage.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, StartPosition.y - ImageSize.y, 0);
                MainImage.sprite = SecondImage.sprite;
                SecondImage.sprite = null;
                TopLock = true;
            }
        }
        if (!RightLock)
        {
            if (SecondImage.transform.localPosition.x < StartPosition.x)
            {
                MainImage.transform.Translate(ImageSize.y * Time.deltaTime / SwipeTime, 0, 0);
                SecondImage.transform.Translate(ImageSize.y * Time.deltaTime / SwipeTime, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                MainImage.transform.localPosition = StartPosition;
                SecondImage.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(StartPosition.x - ImageSize.x, 0, 0);
                MainImage.sprite = SecondImage.sprite;
                SecondImage.sprite = null;
                RightLock = true;
            }
        }
        if (!BottomLock)
        {
            if (SecondImage.transform.localPosition.y > StartPosition.y)
            {
                MainImage.transform.Translate(0, -ImageSize.y * Time.deltaTime / SwipeTime, 0);
                SecondImage.transform.Translate(0, -ImageSize.y * Time.deltaTime / SwipeTime, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                MainImage.transform.localPosition = StartPosition;
                SecondImage.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, StartPosition.y + ImageSize.y, 0);
                MainImage.sprite = SecondImage.sprite;
                SecondImage.sprite = null;
                BottomLock = true;
            }
        }
        if (!LeftLock)
        {
            if (SecondImage.transform.localPosition.x > StartPosition.x)
            {
                MainImage.transform.Translate(-ImageSize.y * Time.deltaTime / SwipeTime, 0, 0);
                SecondImage.transform.Translate(-ImageSize.y * Time.deltaTime / SwipeTime, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                MainImage.transform.localPosition = StartPosition;
                SecondImage.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(StartPosition.x + ImageSize.x, 0, 0);
                MainImage.sprite = SecondImage.sprite;
                SecondImage.sprite = null;
                LeftLock = true;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Functions
    private Sprite NewImage()
    {
        int NewIndex = Random.Range(0, ImagesList.Length);
        while (ImageIndex == NewIndex)
        {
            NewIndex = Random.Range(0, ImagesList.Length);
        }
        ImageIndex = NewIndex;
        return ImagesList[ImageIndex];
    }
    #endregion
}
```

## Дополнение

Если у вас возникли проблемы при использовании скрипта вот вам уже готовый [пакет файлов](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pgMsnlmWcX6uDYDHlmXUrdBux8ywz8lB). Вам надо будет скачать и импортировать в свой проект с помощью функции `ПКМ на папку Assets > Import package > Custom package`.
После чего скопируйте объект `Background` со своими дочерними объектами...

[image]

...и вставьте в свой проект. Да и ещё...
*Не забывайте менять картинки :-)*